# There is an issue with the movingControls, can someone explain why?

Tags: livecode

I am using movingControls like this(1033 is in myID)

```
if myID is among the lines of the movingControls then beep
```

This is very similar to the example. When I encountered an issue I had livecode ask the moving Controls which returned this

```
image id 1033 of card 1002 of stack "C:/Users/Jeffrey/Desktop/Musyc.livecode"
```

If I am not mistaken 1033 is within this, then how come nothing happens. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is happening because "is among the lines of..." compares entire lines of text.  Your value "1033" doesn't match the string " image id 1033 of card 1002 of stack "C:/Users/Jeffrey/Desktop/Musyc.livecode" ".

Store the long id of your image in myID and you should get a true response (beep).